# Не проходит JSON в запросах

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, reactjs, express

Всем привет! Есть файл сервера на Node. В нем есть 2 запроса на добавление данных в базу и получение из базы. База подключена и работает, запросы срабатывают, но возвращают пустой объект. В чем ошибка?

```
var express = require("express");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var db;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/items", function(req, res){
  db.collection('ITEMS').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(docs);
  })
});

app.post('/items', function (req, res) {
  var item = {
    what: req.body.what,
    category: req.body.category,
    metro: req.body.metro,
    date: req.body.date,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    name: req.body.name
  };
  db.collection('ITEMS').insert(item, function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(item);
  });

});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dataBase', function (err, database) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  db = database;
  app.listen(8001, function () {
    console.log('База норм!');
  });
})

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/items", function(req, res){
  db.collection('ITEMS').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(docs);
  })
});

app.post('/items', function (req, res) {
  var item = {
    what: req.body.what,
    category: req.body.category,
    metro: req.body.metro,
    date: req.body.date,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    name: req.body.name
  };
  db.collection('ITEMS').insert(item, function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(item);
  });

});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dataBase', function
  (err, database) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  db = database;
  app.listen(8001, function () {
    console.log('База норм!');
  });
```

})

Comment: Я только учу Node, до Express еще не дошел....но вижу, что Вы не устанавливаете заголовки на ответ. Это не может влиять?
`res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"})`

Answer (score 0):

Добавил `console.log` в ключевых местах. Покажите что у Вас выводит.

```
var express = require("express");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var db;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/items", function(req, res){
  db.collection('ITEMS').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    console.log(typeof docs, docs);
    res.send(docs);
  })
});

app.post('/items', function (req, res) {
  var item = {
    what: req.body.what,
    category: req.body.category,
    metro: req.body.metro,
    date: req.body.date,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    name: req.body.name
  };
  db.collection('ITEMS').insert(item, function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    console.log(typeof item, item);
    res.send(item);
  });

});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dataBase', function (err, database) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  db = database;
  app.listen(8001, function () {
    console.log('База норм!');
  });
})
```

Comment: Вы думаете через год автор объявится и проверит вашу догадку?)

Comment: Чисто теоретически, да)